# Echo each Category from a table into its own DIV

Tags: php, mysql, html

My problem seems complex to me, but im sure theres a simple way to do this.

Essentially, I have a treatments list. On the MYSQL table the list's items are broken up by category, title, description and price.

I need to echo out each category into a div each, sectioning them off. So, if the user has 4 catagories of items then I should have 4 divs with all the items from each category in each.

I cant call on a cataogory directly, because the category names are what ever the user sets them to.

Is there a way to do this? Possibly even a while inside a while with PHP?

---

@Kaaviar Table column names are in order - Category, Title, Description, Price

@sAc - This is the basic of what im using at the moment, but this just lists everything in order of Category.

```
  <?php

    include 'config.php';

    $treatments = MySQL_query("SELECT * FROM treatments ORDER BY category") or die (MySQL_error('woops') ); 

    while($list = MySQL_fetch_array($treatments)) {

   echo $list['title'];
   echo $list['description'];
   echo $list['price'];


    } 

    ?>
```

@Luke - Your code returns nothing here on my end, with the necessary edits etc.

Thanks,
Warren

Comment: You should also pose your code.

Comment: I think the issue with Luke's code is that he's pointing to $row['category'] and in your select statement you have "ORDER BY catagory". You can either replace "category" in his code with "catagory" or rename the column in your table to "category" which is the correct way to spell it.

catagory != category

Comment: With Lukes code I had removed the order by statement and as for the spelling, apologies, for some reason I keep spelling it wrong here but the table name is the correct spelling and coincides with Lukes example.

Comment: Sorry warren, didnt get any notification of your response as it wasnt on my answer.  Could you post the code of mine you used containing all of your edits?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below, obviously you dont have to use the markup I have demo'ed.

```
$string = '<div><ul>';
$cat = '';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  if ($row['category'] != $cat && !empty($cat)) {
    $string .= '</ul></div><div><ul>';
  }
  $string .= '<li>' . $row['title'] . '</li>';
  $cat = $row['category'];
}
$string .= '</ul></div>';
```

Hope it helps

Luke